# Iterating through the first digits in each line of an imported text file in Python

Tags: python, file, loops, text, import

I'm trying to iterate through the first number in each line of a text file. Here's my code:

```
f = open('test.txt')
for line in iter(f):
    print line[1]
f.close()
```

And here's the text file I'm trying to iterate through:

```
[11, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 66)]
[10, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 66.69)]
[9, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 67)]
[7, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 69)]
[6, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 69.69)]
[8, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 74)]
[11, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 75.86)]
[11, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 76)]
[12, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 76.69)]
[13, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 77.86)]
```

Unfortunately this code produces the values 1, 1, 9, 7, etc. instead of what I'm looking for (11, 10, 9, 7, etc.). I'm a Python neophyte. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
line = "[11, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 66)]"

from ast import literal_eval
print literal_eval(line)[0]
11
```

`line[0]` in your code is `[`,  `line[1]`  is `1` etc.. so that is why you are getting single characters.

[literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) will turn your line into an actual `list`, then you can index it as you would any list to access whichever element you require.

You could also use `re` to search for `\d+` one or more consecutive digits:

```
line = r"[11, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 66)]"
import re
print re.findall("\d+",line)[0]
11
```

Third option use `lstrip` and `split`:

```
line = "[11, (28, 33, 45, 55, 62, 66)]"

print line.lstrip("[").split(",")[0]
11
```

`lstrip("[")` removes the `[`, we then `split` on a comma and get the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Right now each line is simply being treated as a string, because of that, you are looking at the second character of each line (remember the first is at 0), which gives you only the first digit of the first number.

What you need to do is evaluate each line as a list of elements rather than a string, then the 0th element will be '11', '10', etc.

Answer (score 0):

I find Padraic answer with use of eval very straightforward and nice, because of format of data in input file, but if you would like to use regular expressions:

```
import re
f = open('test.txt')
for line in iter(f):
    print re.match("\[(\d*)", line).group(1)
```

for refrence: Python `re` doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html